# Filter PivotTable on Top 10 records

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table

I have a spreadsheet with columns like `var1`, `var2`and `var3` with an aggregated (Total) column at the end. What I need is a PivotTable, based on Top 10 highest Totals.

Is that possible?

When I try to filter the table, I can only see the individual records as filter criteria, not the usual Excel filtering options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the facility is available within the PivotTable by filtering the Rows (the funnel next to `var1`), Value Filters, Top 10..., `Top` `10` `Items` by `Sum of Total`:

[image: SO30951042 example]